# How to load multiple JSON files from a list and open each file separately using python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list

Basically, I have a list of JSON files in a list like this :

```
json_files = ['file1.json', 'file2.json', 'file3.json']
```

My goal is to open each of these JSON files and load them into a variable called data. Something like this, but for all of the JSON files in the list as currently I only can open one at a time, making it hardcoded.

```
with open("file1.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

The reason for opening and loading the JSON file into the data variable is for me to access key values from the JSON file, like data["key"]. I have functions in the same file which call these values in this format.

So far, I've tried writing a for loop like the following:

```
json_files = ['file1.json', 'file2.json', 'file3.json']
         
for files in json_files:
    with open(files, "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
```

However, this only opens and loads the JSON object from the last file in the list. How should I proceed if I need to extract certain values from each of the JSON files at the time they are opened?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to avoid overwrite on data variable:

```
complete = []
    for i in json_files:
        with open(files, "r") as f:
            complete.append(json.load(f))
```

Comment: hi, while this would work to avoid overwrite, how would I proceed if I want each of the JSON files to be loaded into a variable? This is because for each JSON file that is loaded into a variable, I am intending to access several values from each of the files.